# PHP регулярные выражения [ replace ]

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, replace

Доброго времени суток, прошу помочь по замене выражений в html коде [ парсинг ].

Сейчас использую парсер со следующей логикой (ниже пример для YouTube)

выделение уникального фрагмента (ED96RtfF22E) html кода с YouTube и заключение в свой внутренний тег [YouTube] у себя на сайте

Источник:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ED96RtfF22E" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Использую:

```
replace|0|#<iframe[^>]*youtube\.com\/embed\/([^"]*)"[^>]*>[^<]*<\/iframe>#|[YouTube]$1[/YouTube]|1|
```

на базе этой логики нужно заменить части html кода в изображении

Источник: содержит ненужный хвост после .jpg (?12345)

```
<img alt="" src="xxx.com/ooo.jpg?12345">
```

НУЖНО: заменить без этого хвоста в окончании

```
<img alt="" src="xxx.com/ooo.jpg">
```

выглядеть должно в таком виде, как на примере вверху, где ... места для необходимых регулярных php выражений

```
replace|0|...|...|1|
```

Буду признателен за помощь!

Comment: Класс, где Ваши натужные попытки решения? :) Для 2 вообще лучше взять вылизанный BB-парсер, чем строить своё решение.

Comment: спасибо, вариант проверенного парсера рассматриваю как раз (предложите если знаете таковые плз), но с этими кейсами прошу помочь тут по их "регулярке"

Comment: Регулярки не всесильны, так что сделайте по уму. Найти парсеры легко в интернете, но лучше обратите внимание на это: http://php.net/manual/ru/intro.bbcode.php

Comment: Изменил условия, для лучшего понимания ситуации

Answer (score 1):

Если это у вас действительно php, то можно сделать так

```
replace|0|#<img[^>]+?src="xxx\.com[^\?">]*\K\?[^"]+#||1|
```

Тест https://regex101.com/r/RPSPdU/1

Эта часть регулярки `<img[^>]+?src="xxx\.com[^\?">]*` делает проверку на то, что мы внутри тега `img` и ссылка идет на сайт `xxx.com` (тут вы можете указать свое условие, так как из вопроса не совсем понятно, какие ссылки нужно обработать) и захватывает текст до знака вопроса в ссылке (или до окончания ссылки, если знака вопроса нет).

`\K` сбрасывает то, что было захвачено предыдущей частью регулярного выражения.

`\?[^"]+` захватывает знак вопроса из ссылки и все символы до окончания ссылки (то есть до символа кавычек).

В результате из текста `<img alt="" src="xxx.com/ooo.jpg?12345">` будет захвачена подстрока `?12345`, которая заменяется на строку нулевой длины.

P.S. Можно чуть изменить регулярку и замену, если строку нулевой длины не примет:

```
replace|0|#<img[^>]+?src="xxx\.com[^\?">]*\K\?[^"]+"#|"|1|
```

Comment: Visman спасибо вам большое за столь развернутый ответ +тест!! Вот это профессионализм, это чувствуется. Обязательно проверю при новом парсинге тк тут уже не дождавшись (нужно было оперативно) решил в тексте "ручками".

PS. А как вам такое решение этого вопроса, кажущееся весьма странным, предложенного с другой площадки:
`replace|0|~\?.*"~|"|1|`

Comment: Вот так https://regex101.com/r/82DYyt/1

Comment: ну да.. это лажа))

Comment: Visman, кстати говоря, не подскажете ссылки на толковые примеры/ описание работы с регулярками в php? Новая для меня тема, но вот пришлось столкнуться и начать грызть гранит)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%E5%E3%F3%EB%FF%F0%ED%FB%E5_%E2%FB%F0%E0%E6%E5%ED%E8%FF http://php.net/manual/ru/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php